# How to setup dependent components of python spark job on aws EMR cluster

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I've wrote a spark program, which needs to be executed on EMR cluster. But there are some dependent files and modules being used by python program. So is there any way around to setup dependent components on a running cluster ? 
Can we mount the s3 bucket and mount that one cluster nodes, and can put all the dependent component on s3 ? Is this a good idea, and using Python how we can mount the s3 buckets on EMR ?

Comment: Are you talking about spark-submit?

Comment: Yes, I was running the program using spark-submit.

Comment: What are your arguments?

Comment: So I didn't provide any arguments, when I setup the cluster, but there were some modules and some files, which were imported by the application. And when I ran the python application, those absent modules threw exception.

Comment: Can you show that exception?

Comment: Unfortunately I've terminated the cluster and removed the logs. I got fix to this using bootstrap scripts and perform all the installations or setup during cluster setup.

Answer (score 0):

- (During cluster creation): You can use Amazon EMR bootstrap [custom actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html) which is capable of executing a bash script at the time of creation of the cluster. You can install all the dependent components using this script. Bootstrap action will be performed on all nodes of the cluster.
- (On a running cluster): You can use Amazon EMR step option to create a [s3-dist-cp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-commandrunner.html) command-runner step to copy files from s3.